# jQuery not working in zen theme

Tags: javascript, theming

Ive put this code before the closing head tag in my html.tpl.php but nothing is happening. Im using the zen theme. Ive tried clearing my cache.

Im I somehow missing a syntax error or is this a Zen/ Drupal qwerk?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('hi');
    });
</script>

</head>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be helpful to know what version of drupal you are using.

Modifying `html.tpl.php` to add Javascript like this is really a bad choice as it is a very brittle way of coding something.

Jquery in Drupal 7 is loaded using the [`noConflict` mechanism](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). This avoids javascript namespace collisions:

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just
>   as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so
>   all functionality is available without using $. If we need to use
>   another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, we can return control of
>   $ back to the other library with a call to $.noConflict():

If you wanted to use code like you've written you would write:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        alert('hi');
    });
</script>
```

You're better off adding a `scripts[]` entry into your `theme_name.info` file and placing such code in its own javascript file in your theme directory. Drupal will load it into the HTML `<head>` for you and aggregate your javascript files for you if you have aggregation turned on.

```
# In YOURTHEME.info
scripts[]= js/example.js

/* Example /sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME/js/example.js */
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('nav ul.primary-menu').append('<div class="nav-blackhole"></div>');
});
```

Comment: html.tpl.php is not used before Drupal 7. I hope the OP is not using that with Drupal 6. `:)`